# Jenkins Extensible Choice Plugin System Groovy Choice Parameter not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am hoping to use a Groovy script that generates a list of jobs on a Jenkins instance as a build parameter. The script works in Jenkins' Script Console:
[image]
but does not work in the job:
[image]
I get the same result if I `import` any of `jenkins.*`, `jenkins.model.*`, `hudson.*`, or `hudson.model.*` into the script, as referenced in the Script Console.
When I try to test the script in Configure, I am unable to with or without using the Groovy Sandbox. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing some imports:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*

jobNames = []
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each{ 
    jobNames.add(it.name.toString())
}
return jobNames
```

Comment: Thank you very much! P.S. I also had to uncheck Use Groovy Sandbox.

Comment: Yes, no sandbox